# How to skip few iterations in a for loop based on a if condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a for loop and I'm looking for a way to skip few iterations whenever that condition is satisfied. How can I do it in python?

Here's an example when condition is satisfied for the first time,

```
for i in range(0, 200000):
    # (when 0 % 300 it meets this criteria) 
    if (i % 300) == 0:             
        # whenever this condition is met skip 4 iterations forward
        # now skip 4 iterations --- > (0, 1, 2, 3)

    # now continue from 4th iteration until the condition is met again
```

Similarly, this should happens whenever if condition is satisfied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Skipping 4 steps after each meeting condition (`(i % 300) == 0`) is equal to skipping `0`, `1`, `2`, and `3`. You can simply change the condition to skip all these steps with `(i % 300) < 4`.

```
for i in range(0, 200000):
    # (when 0 % 300 it meets this criteria) 
    if (i % 300) < 4: # Skips iteration when remainder satisfier condition            
    #if (i % 300) in (0,1,2,3): # or alternative skip condition
        # whenever this condition is met skip 4 iterations forward
        # now skip 4 iterations --- > (0, 1, 2, 3)
        continue

    # now continue from 4th iteration 
    print(i)
```

Comment: Thank you. This also working fine. I didn't understood why did you use < 4? Can you explain this a bit. I'm totally new.

Comment: It's `< 4` because that condition will be true for the 4 times you want to skip. It might break if you want to, say, iterate over a set. (But it works fine for this :)

Comment: @GeeTransit How will it be true for four times? Can you explain it a bit?

Comment: I extended the answer with explanation.

Comment: Got it. This answer is simpler. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can save the iterator (`range`) in a variable and call `next(it)` on it when you need it. Note that this will discard those values.

```py
# Note that we call iter to get an iterator. `range` is an iterable
# that returns another iterator so that it can be used multiple
# times in a for loop.
it = iter(range(200000))

for i in it:
    if not i%300:
        for _ in range(4): # 4 is the amount of values to skip
            i = next(it)   # Update `i` for use later on

    # `i` will never be a multiple of 300; it is updated above
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you. This is working fine.